# How do you unit test mixins in Dart?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mixins

I can find no documentation on this. The only way I see is to test a class that has the mixin added, but this is not a sound way of testing.

Comment: Why is it not a sound way of testing?

Comment: Create a class in the context of the test with the mixin(s) to test, then write tests for the mixin methods there.

Comment: @nvoigt because you wouldn't be testing it as a unit, but as Eddie Lopez suggests it's just a matter of creating an empty class and adding the mixin to that. It just puzzled me that I couldn't find a direct way of testing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/// example mixin
///
mixin TestMixin {
  String testing(String abc) {
    print("your function logic goes here");
    return abc;
  }
}

/// This is just a helper class to get all the [mixin] functions
///
class FunctionHoldingClassForMixin with TestMixin {}
```

**Now you can use this in main function as shown below.**

```
void main() {
  late FunctionHoldingClassForMixin mockClass;
  setUp(() {
    mockClass = FunctionHoldingClassForMixin();
  });

  test("mention what you wanna test", () {
    var result = mockClass.testing("testing abc");
    expect(result, "testing abc");
  });
}
```

- Hope this resolves your equery ‍.
- In case if someone finds a better approach do comment to improve the answer.
- Thank you